# Распаковка bz2 архива с помощью исходного кода bzip2, инициализация bz_stream

Tags: c++, qt, bz2

Здравствуйте! Имеется необходимость распаковывать `bz2` архив внутри программы. Из вариантов - `boost` и `bzip2`. Решил выбрать второе, т.к. весит меньше и работает быстрее (вроде). Однако я столкнулся с рядом проблем. Скачал исходный код с сайта [bzip.org](http://www.bzip.org/) и открыл [документацию](http://www.bzip.org/1.0.5/bzip2-manual-1.0.5.html). Совершенно ясно, что необходимо использовать функции пунктов 3.3.4-3.3.6, но во всех них написано следующее:

> a `bz_stream` record should be allocated and initialised before the call

Но **нигде** в документации не написано, *каким* образом инициализировать bz_stream для декомпрессии архива. Совершенно не понимаю, как пользоваться функциями и ссылаться на файл. Очень прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В доках, в п. 3.3.1 написано, что `bz_stream` это простая структура:

```
typedef struct {
  char *next_in;
  unsigned int avail_in;
  unsigned int total_in_lo32;
  unsigned int total_in_hi32;

  char *next_out;
  unsigned int avail_out;
  unsigned int total_out_lo32;
  unsigned int total_out_hi32;

  void *state;

  void *(*bzalloc)(void *,int,int);
  void (*bzfree)(void *,void *);
  void *opaque;
} bz_stream;
```

Инициализация:

```
    bz_stream bz;

    bz.next_in = NULL;
    bz.avail_in = 0;
    bz.bzalloc = NULL;
    bz.bzfree = NULL;
    bz.opaque = NULL;

    int ret = BZ2_bzDecompressInit(&bz, 0, 0);

    if (ret != BZ_OK) {
        printf("Error occurred during BZIP initialization. BZIP error code: %d", ret);
    }
```

Далее, перед каждым вызовом `BZ2_bzDecompress` вам надо инициализировать поля `*_in` и `*_out`:

```
   bz.next_in = <указатель на сжатые данные>;
   bz.avail_in = <размер данных>;

   bz.next_out = <указатель на буфер>;
   bz.avail_out = <размер буфера>;

   ret = BZ2_bzDecompress(&bz); 
   ...
```